# A hash being passed in to applications

Tags: facebook, hash

Does Facebook pass in some kind of a hash calculated out of user ID, application ID and application secret (but not limited to that) to applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

signed request is probably what u are looking for (signed req contains the userID info if that user has authorized your app beforehand ....but it is not calc based on user ID)

Comment: Hi Eddy, do you know how the signed request is calculated? I need to know the exact algorithm so that I can calculate it on my server whenever a user connects and then compare it against the one calculated by Facebook and see if they match, which would mean the user is valid. Also, where to get this signed request from?

Comment: get the php sdk and you should have the code that helps to "decode" it.